# strings won't give anything got from json

Tags: php, file-get-contents

no idea how im supposed to put the title, but here is the code:

```
if(isset($stats->playerStatus->server->serverIPv6Address)){ // prefer the IPv6 address if it's there`     
    $srvDetails = file_get_contents('https://api.kag2d.com/server/ip/' . $stats->playerStatus->server->serverIPv6Address . '/port/' . $stats->playerStatus->server->serverPort . '/status');
}elseif(isset($stats->playerStatus->server->serverIPv4Address)){
    $srvDetails = file_get_contents('https://api.kag2d.com/server/ip/' . $stats->playerStatus->server->serverIPv4Address . '/port/' . $stats->playerStatus->server->serverPort . '/status');
}


$srvContent   = json_decode($srvDetails, true);
$srvName      = $srvContent->serverName;
$playerString = 'Players: ' . $srvContent->currentPlayers . '/' . $srvContent->maxPlayers;
```

and $srvName keeps empty and $playerString is just Players: /
take https://api.kag2d.com/server/ip/199.168.184.8/port/23002/status as an example
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an object, the result of `json_decode` is an array, due to the second parameter being true.

Either remove that parameter or change the access to be of array style.

This error could have been easily spotted with basic debugging skills and a call to `var_dump($srvContent)`.

*Update*
The following code works for me:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.kag2d.com/server/ip/199.168.184.8/port/23002/status");
var_dump($json);
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($decoded);
var_dump(json_last_error());
```

Result of the second dump:

```
array(1) {
  'serverStatus' =>
  array(24) {
    'DNCycle' =>
    int(0)
    'DNState' =>
    int(0)
    'build' =>
    int(830)
    'connectable' =>
    int(1)
    'currentPlayers' =>
    int(2)
    'description' =>
    string(58) "Dreams, neon dreams, neon life, you will find, your, song."
    'firstSeen' =>
    string(19) "2012-07-10 18:26:53"
    'gameMode' =>
    string(15) "Team Deathmatch"
    'gameState' =>
    int(1)
    'gid' =>
    int(1)
    'gold' =>
    int(1)
    'lastUpdate' =>
    string(19) "2013-07-30 19:55:39"
    'mapH' =>
    int(122)
    'mapW' =>
    int(870)
    'maxPlayers' =>
    int(10)
    'maxSpectatorPlayers' =>
    int(0)
    'password' =>
    int(1)
    'playerList' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'reservedPlayers' =>
    int(0)
    'serverIPv4Address' =>
    string(13) "199.168.184.8"
    'serverIPv6Address' =>
    string(17) "2001:470:4:727::6"
    'serverName' =>
    string(38) "TROUBLE - Beyond - password on forums."
    'serverPort' =>
    int(23002)
    'spectatorPlayers' =>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

What about you?

Comment: the strings are exactly the same, still empty

Comment: And have you used `var_dump()` to investigate the structure you are trying to use?

Comment: Then the JSON is invalid and cannot be decoded (or it is nested too deep - unlikely). Can you make a call to [json_last_error()](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) after the decode and dump that result as well. ALso see my update in the answer.